# Problem: Ufw Enabled with Deny/Deny, however SSH Inbound still works. Please help

Tags: 12.04, ufw

In order to lock down my server, i installed ubuntu with ufw. I run a VM inside the server that hosts a ssh server.

I opened the server and ran UFW and set Deny to send and Deny to Recieve. Now it looks like the server is blocked from inbound and outbound, which is good... BUT, when I tried to use my other laptop to ssh into the Server's VM, IT STILL GOT IN. Why is that?

Server:
Ubuntu 1204
ufw ON, DENY DENY enabled
Virtualbox, with VM(Xubuntu 1204, installed sshd)

My laptop:
Ubuntu 1204

Can you help me fix this problem so that ufw BLOCKS the Virtualbox Ubuntu VM also?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check the IP address that you are SSH'ing to. Can you provide the **ufw** settings (command line, or file)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect that traffic from a remote machine to a VM is going to use the `forward` policy, not the `send` or `receive` policies.

Generally, the input/receive versus forward classification is based on whether the destination address is local to the host. The address of a virtual guest is considered foreign.

Try changing the default forward policy in `/etc/default/ufw` and see if the behavior changes.